# Obtaining a previous value from a column and differencing in R

Tags: r, data.table, xts

I have a bit of a question about obtaining a previous value from one column and putting it into another column. I have a `data.table` object (which can easily be converted into an `xts` object) as follows:

The `dput` output is as follows:

```
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1122855314, 1122855315, 1122855316, 
1122855317, 1122855318, 1122855319, 1122855320, 1122955811, 1122955812, 
1122955813, 1122955814, 1123027212, 1123027213, 1123027214, 1123027215, 
1123027216, 1123027217), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Australia/Melbourne"), 
`Inventory_{t}` = c(0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 7, 6, 6, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 3, 3, 3), `Inventory_{t-1}` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Delta Inventory_{t-1}` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Time", 
"Inventory_{t}", "Inventory_{t-1}", "Delta Inventory_{t-1}"), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000028b0788>)
```

I would like to 'fill in' the "Inventory_{t-1}" such that it takes the value which was in "Inventory_{t}" one second earlier and puts it into that cell. Similarly, for "Delta Inventory_{t-1}" I want it to be equal to `Delta Inventory_{t-1} = Inventory_{t-1} - Inventory_{t-2}`
I should also note that at the start of each new day, the initial values for "Inventory_{t-1}" and "Delta Inventory_{t-1}" must be 0.

With this information, I would like to get a new `data.table`/`xts` object which looks like this:

```
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1122855314, 1122855315, 1122855316, 
1122855317, 1122855318, 1122855319, 1122855320, 1122955811, 1122955812, 
1122955813, 1122955814, 1123027212, 1123027213, 1123027214, 1123027215, 
1123027216, 1123027217), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Australia/Melbourne"), 
`Inventory_{t}` = c(0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 7, 6, 6, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 3, 3, 3), `Inventory_{t-1}` = c(0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 8, 0, 
7, 6, 6, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3), `Delta Inventory_{t-1}` = c(0, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 7, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0)), .Names = c("Time", 
"Inventory_{t}", "Inventory_{t-1}", "Delta Inventory_{t-1}"), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000028b0788>)
```

The things is, this issue is very straightforward for me to solve if I use loops, but since I have so much data I was hoping for a much faster way to do this, so if anyone can help me out with this I'd really appreciate it, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, have a look at the `shift()` function in the `data.table` package.

Comment: @Uwe Thanks, so by the look of it`shift(z$`Inventory_{t}`, type ="lag", fill=0)` seems to work, but how can I do it by day? (i.e. how do I make it so that the `Inventory_{t-1}` column has 0 as the first value for each day?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using the `shift()` function. The OP has requested to restart the calculation anew every day. This is accomplished by the `by =` parameter:

```
z[, `:=`(`Inventory_{t-1}` = shift(`Inventory_{t}`, fill = 0),
         `Delta Inventory_{t-1}` = shift(`Inventory_{t}`, fill = 0) - 
           shift(`Inventory_{t}`, n = 2L, fill = 0)), by = .(Day = as.Date(Time))][]
```

> ```
>                    Time Inventory_{t} Inventory_{t-1} Delta Inventory_{t-1}
>  1: 2005-08-01 10:15:14             0               0                     0
>  2: 2005-08-01 10:15:15             2               0                     0
>  3: 2005-08-01 10:15:16             2               2                     2
>  4: 2005-08-01 10:15:17             2               2                     0
>  5: 2005-08-01 10:15:18             5               2                     0
>  6: 2005-08-01 10:15:19             8               5                     3
>  7: 2005-08-01 10:15:20             3               8                     3
>  8: 2005-08-02 14:10:11             7               0                     0
>  9: 2005-08-02 14:10:12             6               7                     7
> 10: 2005-08-02 14:10:13             6               6                    -1
> 11: 2005-08-02 14:10:14             1               6                     0
> 12: 2005-08-03 10:00:12             0               0                     0
> 13: 2005-08-03 10:00:13             1               0                     0
> 14: 2005-08-03 10:00:14             1               1                     1
> 15: 2005-08-03 10:00:15             3               1                     0
> 16: 2005-08-03 10:00:16             3               3                     2
> 17: 2005-08-03 10:00:17             3               3                     0
> ```